# Adding text to string in JCombo Box Java

Tags: java, string, swing, combobox

I am working on an assignment in Java and am stuck on how to do this: Full code is below

JTextField descripField = new JTextField(20);
   // add your desired TV programs to the string

String[] progs = {               };
   // add your desired TV programs descrips to the string

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JTVDownload extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
   JComboBox<String> programBox = new JComboBox<String>();
   JLabel programList = new JLabel("***                  Program List               ***");
   JLabel stars = new JLabel("*****************************");
   JTextField descripField = new JTextField(20);
   // add your desired TV programs to the string


   String[] progs = {               };
   // add your desired TV programs descrips to the string
   String[] descrips = {              };
   public JTVDownload()
   {
      super("JTVDownload");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      programBox.addItemListener(this);
      add(stars);
      add(programList);
      programBox.addItem("none");
      for(int x = 0; x < progs.length; ++x)
         programBox.addItem(progs[x]);
      add(programBox);
      add(descripField);
   }
   public static void main(String[] arguments)
   {
      JTVDownload frame = new JTVDownload();
      frame.setSize(300,150);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
   @Override
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list)
   {
      Object source = list.getSource();
      if(source == programBox)
      {
         int num = programBox.getSelectedIndex();
         descripField.setText(descrips[num]);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First `progs` and `descrips` will need to have some text added to them them.  The problem is, you add `none`, which makes the two lists out of sync, probably better to include it in your arrays

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JTVDownload extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

    JComboBox<String> programBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    JLabel programList = new JLabel("***                  Program List               ***");
    JLabel stars = new JLabel("*****************************");
    JTextField descripField = new JTextField(20);
    // add your desired TV programs to the string

    String[] progs = {"None", "Happy days", "Here's Lucy", "That 70's Show"};
    // add your desired TV programs descrips to the string
    String[] descrips = {"", "Happy days", "Here's Lucy", "That 70's Show"};

    public JTVDownload() {
        super("JTVDownload");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        programBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(stars);
        add(programList);
        for (int x = 0; x < progs.length; ++x) {
            programBox.addItem(progs[x]);
        }
        add(programBox);
        add(descripField);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        JTVDownload frame = new JTVDownload();
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list) {
        Object source = list.getSource();
        if (source == programBox) {
            int num = programBox.getSelectedIndex();
            descripField.setText(descrips[num]);
        }
    }
}
```

Overall, a better solution would be to use a POJO to wrap up the "name" and "description" into a single object, that way you're carrying the information together in a single unit of work.  This of cause, would then require you to have a `ListCellRenderer` to customise how the object is rendered. In that case, take a closer look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details